# Calling two state updater functions that depend on each other in an onClick event handler in React?

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, state, jsx

If i'm calling two state updater functions in an onClick event handler, and the second state updater function uses the state, updated by the first state updater function, than the second state updates by the previous or default value of the first state. How can I update two states that depend on each other in an event handler?

For example,
when pressing the button element, we'll see 2 in the p element instead of 11. Only after the second press, it will show 11.

```
export default function Stage() {
    const [a, setA] = React.useState(1);
    const [b, setB] = React.useState(1);

    function updateA(x) {
        setA(x);
    };
    function updateB() {
        setB(1 + a);
    };

    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => {updateA(10); updateB()}}></button>
        <p>{b}</p>
    </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: in the updateB function will x be dynamic? where will x come from?

Comment: The example wasn't exact. (Now it's edited) updateA gets the parameter x, and updateB uses a but it doesn't get a parameter. The point is the same.

Comment: Creating a useEffect hook, calling the updateB function inside and passing it a as a second argument solved the problem. The onClick event now only calls the updateA function with a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utilize the lifecycle hook useEffect to create sideEffects when A updates to then set your B state.

```
export default function Stage() {
    const [a, setA] = React.useState(1);
    const [b, setB] = React.useState(1);


    function updateA(x) {
        setA(x);
    };

  useEffect(() => {
  function updateB() {
        setB(1 + a);
    };
  },[a])

    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => updateA(10)></button>
        <p>{b}</p>
    </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: This really worked, but didn't you only mean to call the updateB function inside the useEffect hook instead of defining it there?

Comment: depends.. do you need to use the function outside of the useEffect doesn't look like it in this example

Answer (score -1):

When your states in a component depend each other this is an *antipattern* (Don't Sync State), try to avoid it and redesign a component.

Instead minimaze state and derive from it:

```js
export default function Stage() {
    const [a, setA] = React.useState(1);

    function updateA(a) {
        setA(10);
    };

    function updateB(x) {
        return a+x
    };

    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => {updateA(1)}></button>
        <p>{updateB(1)}</p>
    </div>
    )
};
```

P.S. setState is async operation and in your example line *updateA(1); updateB(1)* is assumed to work sync

Comment: welcome. But the main idea is to minimaze state and avoid state synchronization. I would recommend to read that - https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-sync-state-derive-it